# Moving certain Files with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am attempting to move all our daily files from a listing in excel. Column D has the Source, `D:\Hard drive\Lee’s Hard Drive\My Documents\WBD052U_PRINT01*.txt` Column E has Destination, `C:\Users\Lee\Documents\Work\01. WBD52U`

When I run the macro I get the following error

> Run time error 13. Type mismatch.

If I just do 1 line i.e.

```
FromPath Range(D5:D5) ToPath Range (E5:E5)
```

this works perfectly.

As soon as I specify greater range it does not work. Thank you I really need some help.

```
   Sub Move_Certain_Files()

Dim fso, MyFile
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String


FromPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D5:D6") '<< Change
ToPath = ActiveSheet.Range("E5:E6")   '<< Change


On Error Resume Next
Kill FromPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D5:D6")
On Error GoTo 0


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error Resume Next

fso.copyFile (FromPath), ToPath, True
MsgBox "File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"


fso.copyFile Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Honestly, why are you using VBA to move files around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because you're trying to set a range to a String variable (FromPath). You'd need to set it to a Range variable, using Set. We're going to want to work through each item in that range. It's easiest to work through a single column range (we can reference stuff to the side easily at the same time). Also, rather than working through the range to pick up and then do the copy work later, we can do the copy work directly as we work through the range. Here we go:

```
Sub Move_Certain_Files()

    Dim fso, MyFile
    Dim pathsRng As Range

    'Set range here, just the first [FROM path] column:
    Set pathsRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D5:D6")

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next

    'Loop through paths range to copy from FROM path and paste
    'to TO path (TO path is found by using relative address (1, 2):
    For Each pathItem In pathsRng
        fso.CopyFile (pathItem.Value), pathItem(1, 2).Value, True
    Next pathItem

    'Display success/failure message:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File(s) Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: Some files may not have copied.", vbInformation, "Done!"
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Additional: I meant to ask, I am not sure of your intention with the line:

```
Kill FromPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D5:D6")
```

Do you wish to delete the source files after copying? If so, you should do that after copying using a loop - OR you could just move the files instead of copy: In my code above you would change the following line:

```
fso.CopyFile (pathItem.Value), pathItem(1, 2).Value, True
```

to this:

```
fso.MoveFile (pathItem.Value), pathItem(1, 2).Value
```

Comment: Hi David
1st thank you ever so much the code works brilliantly and you have helped me understand where I was going wrong. Which helps in my future coding practices. The kill fromPath was if it exists don't copy but it appears to work brilliantly and doesn't need anything like this. 
I actually have 78 lines of daily file that have to be copied from a shared file drive each day. I can use this now for various departments to to copy their required reports without people having to spend wasted hours. Much appreciated. Lee

Comment: Hi Lee, I'm really pleased the revised code works well! Sounds like a nice efficiency you've created. Please can you click to accept my answer? :-) Cheers